# Identify only visible features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, features, thematic-map, identify

I have a thematic map layer Rekryterare in QGIS. The layer is defined as identifiable. The question is how can I make the thematic categories of this map layer unidentifiable when they are invisible on the map? (see the attached picture).

Right now I can click the invisible points on the map and read the feature attributes and this is not what I want, I would like to have the invisible points unselectable. Anyone know how I can solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is due to the way you set up your style.  You have used a categorised style.

Change your style to Rule-based.  This effectively filters the data per thematic layer.  It will then behave as you expect when you turn on and off thematic layers.  You don't then have to do `Content->Filter` (or `Layer->Query`)every time you want to restrict the identification.  You can just turn on and off themes.

Comment: Thanks! now i have learned something good. But unfortunately it seems that it does not work in my case since I combine it with the "Point displacement" function. Once I choose the Point displacement style, and then pick Rule based as the renderer, I cannot turn on or off the categories of the layer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the only way to disable identifying the invisible classes is to use the Filter option by `right-click the layer in the table of Content -> Filter` and build a query:

`"Rekryterare" = 'Carina K'`

It will show only `'Carina K'` and completely hide other categories and make it unidentifiable.

Comment: This works well for a one-off situation, but there is a better way.  See my answer.

Comment: +1 from me. I completely forgot that rule-based has internal filtering. Anyway, I will keep my answer for future reference.

Comment: Thanks - yes do keep your answer because it is legitimate and useful as a quick solution where you don't want to re-do your style.